# Spring AWS S3 select query

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

how can i pull an object out of S3 bucket, a file. and read it into a object in spring-boot and java. So i have a file in S3 that contains multiple json rows, i want to read it from there into a list of objects.

now im following this example:

https://codetinkering.com/aws-s3-select-api-java-example/

which works if i want to stream it, but i want to read into a list of objects.

The file contains multiple rows of data as such, each row is a json object, in AWS ui this works fine with a s3 select

```
{
   "name":"ABC"
   "surname":"DEF"
}
{
   "name":"ABC"
   "surname":"DEF"
}
```

Comment: Just do an S3 `GetObject`!? S3 select is really only useful if you want to filter the rows and columns.

Comment: Can you please share sample file content present in S3 bucket?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal edited above

Comment: Thanks for sharing, in file each json is present in multiple rows or single row?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal  multiple rows

Comment: @user1555190 -  I have added implementation as per your requirement. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the implementation, first add this dependency in pom.xml

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.285</version>
         </dependency>
```

**File content** - This file (filename.txt) is present in AWS S3 bucket

```
{
   "name":"rohit",
   "surname":"sharma"
}
{
   "name":"virat",
   "surname":"kohli"
}
```

**Java Classes**

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class AwsS3ClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public S3Client s3Client(){
        AwsBasicCredentials awsBasicCredentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create("ACCESS_KEY_ID", "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY");
        return S3Client
                .builder()
                .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsBasicCredentials))
                .build();
    }
}
```

**AwsS3Service V1 - *Reading S3 file records and create object list***

```
@Service
public class AwsS3Service {

    private final S3Client s3Client;

    @Autowired
    public AwsS3Service(S3Client s3Client) {
        this.s3Client = s3Client;
    }


    public List<Person> readFileAndCreateList(String bucketName, String keyName) throws IOException {
        final Path file = readFile(bucketName, keyName);
        return convertFileToList(file);
    }

    private Path readFile(String bucketName, String keyName) throws IOException {
        GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                .builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .key(keyName)
                .build();

        final byte[] bytes = s3Client
                .getObject(getObjectRequest)
                .readAllBytes();
        final Path path = Paths.get("demo.txt");
        Files.write(path, bytes);
        return path;
    }

    private List<Person> convertFileToList(Path path) throws IOException {
        final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        List<Person> persons=new ArrayList<>();
        for (String line : lines) {
            if ("{".equals(line)) {
                json = new StringBuilder("{");
            } else if ("}".equals(line)) {
                json.append("}");
               persons.add(new ObjectMapper()
                        .readValue(json.toString(), Person.class));
            } else {
                json.append(line.trim());
            }
        }
        return persons;
    }
}
```

**AwsS3Service V2 - *Reading S3 file records in-memory and create object list***

```
@Service
public class AwsS3Service {

    private final S3Client s3Client;

    @Autowired
    public AwsS3Service(S3Client s3Client) {
        this.s3Client = s3Client;
    }


    public List<Person> readFileAndCreateObjectList(String bucketName, String keyName) throws IOException {
        final List<String> lines = readFile(bucketName, keyName);
        return convertFileLinesToObjectList(lines);
    }

    private List<String> readFile(String bucketName, String keyName) throws IOException {
        GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                .builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .key(keyName)
                .build();

        byte[] bytes;
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            s3Client
                    .getObject(getObjectRequest)
                    .transferTo(byteArrayOutputStream);
            bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        }

        List<String> lines=new ArrayList<>();
        try(ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(byteArrayInputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)){
           while (bufferedReader.ready()){
              lines.add(bufferedReader.readLine());
           }
        }
        return lines;
    }

    private List<Person> convertFileLinesToObjectList(List<String> lines) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String line : lines) {
            if ("{".equals(line)) {
                json = new StringBuilder("{");
            } else if ("}".equals(line)) {
                json.append("}");
                persons.add(new ObjectMapper()
                        .readValue(json.toString(), Person.class));
            } else {
                json.append(line.trim());
            }
        }
        return persons;
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final AwsS3Service awsS3Service;

    @Autowired
    public DemoApplication(AwsS3Service awsS3Service) {
        this.awsS3Service = awsS3Service;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        //KEY_NAME==filename.txt
        final List<Person> peoples =
                awsS3Service
                        .readFileAndCreateList("BUCKET_NAME", "KEY_NAME");
        System.out.println(peoples);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[Person{name='rohit', surname='sharma'}, Person{name='virat', surname='kohli'}]
```

Comment: thank you for that. I could skip cretaing a file and use stream readers ie is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
            bfReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

Comment: Yes you can do that as well. I implemented solution using java.nio classes that adds readability.

Comment: @user1555190 - I have updated my answer with both versions. Please check and see if that helps.

Comment: @user1555190 - if this answer helps request you to please accept the answer so that it help others as well.

Comment: Thanks... i have accepted it. I like the solution.